# Excel Macros to hide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know how to write a macro in Excel, but I think I've found an answer on your site that gets me close to what I need.  Here's my situation:

```
If cell K23 = cell T20 then do nothing.  
If cell K23 = cell (T21:T23) then hide rows 25:65
```

Here's the macro I have so far:

```
Sub HIDE()
    If Range(K23) = Range(T20) Then nil = True
    Else
    If Range(K23) = Range("T21:T23") Then Rows("25:65").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If: End If:

End Sub
```

I get an error that says "Else without If"

Please tell me what I've done wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: your second if needs to be clarified a bit...do you want to hide rows 25:65 if K23 is equal to any value in T21:T23 or all of the values in T21:T23, or the sum of the values.  Can you please write in text what you'd like to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "nil = true" on a separate line; if you have the statement to be executed on the same line as the "if", Excel VBA considers this to be the end of the "if" statement.

So you'd need to do:

```
Sub HIDE()
    If Range(K23) = Range(T20) Then 
        nil = True
    Else
        If Range(K23) = Range("T21:T23") Then 
            Rows("25:65").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It's also a little easier to read this way.  As commented on your question, you'll need to provide a bit more detail in order for us to help you get your function actually doing exactly what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way...

```
Sub tgr()

    Range("25:65").EntireRow.Hidden = (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("T21:T23"), Range("K23").Text) > 0)

End Sub
```